# How do I resolve Java DXA 1.7 java.lang.LinkageError?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.7

I have built yet another fresh Java DXA 1.7 which runs just fine on the local Tomcat 8.0 server in Eclipse Neon.3.

I publish this to an Azure App Service created by using the Azure Toolkit for Java in Eclipse.

When I access the site on Azure it fails with Error:

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/Views/Core/Page/GeneralPage_jsp, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type org/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager used in the signature

Has anyone seen this or know what to do to resolve this error?

Comment: Looks like you may have some jars deployed from a different version of tomcat than the one provided by Azure? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8488916/866454